# Remove Force Unwrapping

Tags: swift, option-type

Remove force unwrapping

```
private func getLanguageCode() -> String {
    return Locale.current.languageCode!
}
```

After removing force unwrapping

```
private func getLanguageCode() -> String? {
    if let language = Locale.current.languageCode {
       return language
    }
    return nil
}
```

Correct??

for this

```
lazy var commonErrorList : Dictionary<String, AnyObject>? = {
        let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "CommonErrorCodes", ofType: "plist")
        return NSDictionary(contentsOfFile: path!) as? [String : AnyObject]
    }()
```

what it should be after removing forced unwrapping?

Comment: you could use `guard` in this case, that'd be more elegant in this situation.

Comment: a downvoting question will demotivate but it's a clear question.

Comment: @holex Whether `guard` is more elegant or not depends on how exceptional the `nil` return would be IMO. In this case, I would agree with you because it would be pretty exceptional for a locale not to have a language code. But that doesn't mean the example here is wrong.

Comment: @JeremyP, both examples are completely valid, that is why I said __'in this case'__ about `guard`, that'd somehow just feel better.

Answer (score 3):

You could just

```
return Locale.current.languageCode
```

without the forced unwrap, if you just return nil anyway.

Answer (score 2):

You may try guard to prevent nested if statement in the future. In guard statement it would be something like this:

```
private func getLanguageCode() throws -> String {
    guard let language = Locale.current.languageCode else {
        throw LanguageError.CanNotGetCode
    }

    return language
}
```

or without throws

```
private func getLanguageCode()-> String? {
    guard let language = Locale.current.languageCode else {
        return nil
    }

    return language
}
```

You may use throwing function if in the future you want to handle your function error.

Answer (score 1):

Your code looks fine to me. You can consider also using `guard` statement.

```
private func getLanguageCode() -> String? {
    guard let language = Locale.current.languageCode else { return nil }
    return language
}
```

Comment: private func createWebContentDownloadDirectory(of type: String, withCountryCode countryCode: String, withLanguageCode languageCode: String, forQAMode mode: Bool) -> URL {
      let downloadDirectoryURL = self.parentDirectoryURL!.appendingPathComponent(fileName)
      return downloadDirectoryURL
    } remove force unwrap...

Answer (score 1):

If you want to return a **non-optional String**, you can just do:

```
private func getLanguageCode() -> String {
    return Locale.current.languageCode ?? ""
}
```

If you prefer to return a **String?**, then:

```
private func getLanguageCode() -> String? {
    return Locale.current.languageCode
}
```

If you still want to detect the nil condition inside your function for whatever reason:

```
private func getLanguageCode() -> String? {
    guard let language = Locale.current.languageCode else { 
        // Do something here...
        return nil     
    }
    return language
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**If you don't want to deal with an unwrap, you can easily do this:**

```
private func getLanguageCode() -> String {
    return Locale.current.languageCode ?? "en"
}
```

This will return the value of the optional if available, otherwise it will return the specified value.

**You can also use a property to get the expected value:**

```
private var getLanguageCode: String {
    return Locale.current.languageCode ?? "en"
}
```

The final result is pretty the same, but you get rid of the '( )' notation :-)